# compiler-cli throws error as dynamic declarations are encountered

Tags: angular, angular2-compiler

So I got here some pretty big project which was developed with idea that at some point as Angular advances to full 2.0 version it shall have AoT compilation enabled and finally I get all API from Angular up and ready to do it, or so it seems ...

First of all project is working really nice in JiT mode with Angular 2 and Typescript 2.0.2 but not so in AoT.

After massive research I've found out that problem lies in a fact that list of my declarations/providers/entryComponents is aggregated dynamically - that is what happens when application is split in many sub modules each of whom can add something to those lists, as it requires. And soon as I try to do something like:

    `@NgModule({
       declarations:[ configuration.declarations ]
    })`

I receive `Error encountered resolving symbol values statically.`

If I output aggregated value in JiT mode and insert here a static list of all those entries from `configuration.declarations` manually, it suddenly starts t work.

So the big questions is - what a hell?! why doesn't it work and how to overcome this?

Just as making big application with all sub component requirements listed in single file manually breaks good code design big time and I better not believe that Angular team that has proven to be a really good at making sane coding layouts would imply that as an only alternative.

Comment: See also https://github.com/qdouble/angular-webpack2-starter#aot--donts

Answer (score 1):

Try using multiple `NgModule`s and import them into the modules that require them. You are trying to duplicate what the compiler does for you using `import` and `export`.

For more information look [here](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/ngmodule-faq.html).